# How to look for thesis of Massachusetts Institute of Technology?

Tags: online-resource

On my book there is the following reference:

Buckles, R. G., 1966, Analysis of gas exchange in a membrane oxygenator, Thesis, Massachusetts Institute of Technology, Cambridge

I tried to find it online:

https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/7582/browse?rpp=20&order=ASC&sort_by=1&etal=-1&type=title&starts_with=A

http://library.mit.edu/F/XQ39BH41Q8C9V3XHXK5XA7EMFR5V5R9QDNSCKDFTNN4JNSS2SF-02835?func=find-b&find_code=WRD&request=Analysis+of+gas+exchange+in+a+membrane+oxygenator )

but without success.
Can you show me where I can find it please?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Most theses, published, are in the controlling or major library for that country - have you tried an inter-library loan request? It may not be online or are you hoping someone else has scanned it to save you the effort...

Comment: Have you tried asking your librarian?

Comment: Hello @astronat, the library of my faculty does not have it.

Comment: @SolarMike now I looking for the email of the MIT's library.

Comment: It's in the MIT library as noncirculating so I don't think a ILL would work. Details wants an MIT login. I searched [here](https://lib.mit.edu/search/bento?q=Buckles+1966).

Comment: Inter-library loan, or order the microfilm version.

Comment: You _might_ find what you need in [the journal version](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/aic.690140505/full).

Comment: Very good @JeffE!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're going to want to ask your institution's library to submit an interlibrary loan request to MIT to access the thesis. MIT will prefer that you go through that channel - it has to do with ILL request statistics.  I'm an academic librarian and have worked in interlibrary loan in the past - trust me, this is your best bet, especially since there's a good chance there isn't a widely available digital copy (as is the case with most theses, dissertations, papers, articles, etc published prior to the mid-90s).

Comment: If an item is listed as noncirculating, can it still be requested (and approved) for a interlibrary loan?